# Can't find what is image.layer in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimageview

I was looking how to make `UIImageView` circle. And all I can find is:
(Image has to be square)

```
 image.layer.cornerRadius = image.frame.size.height/2
 image.clipsToBounds = true
```

But I can't find "image" and "layer" property in apple documentation. So I am not sure how to use it. Now I got such an error:

> use of unresolved identifier 'image'

Note: I have used `image` higher in my code and it was no problem.

[this is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ga4LC.jpg)

Comment: Please post actual code and not images of code, which aren't copy-passable, can't be read by a screen reader, aren't searchable, etc.

Comment: Those are a part of UIImageView not UIImage and you have Image above not image. Swift is case sensitive. Change it to lowercase so you don’t duplicate with SwiftUI Image

Comment: It looks like you just need to replace `image` (which doesn't exist -- you *do* have a `UIImage` with a capitalized variable name, as the error suggests) with `myImage`, which is your `UIImageView`.

Comment: Get out of the habit of shortening type names. If you have a `UIImageView`, call it `myImageView`, not `myImage`. Likewise with a `UIViewController`, call it `myViewController`, not `myView`. A `UIImage` and a `UIImageView` are both valid types in UIKit (and so are `UIView` and `UIViewController`) and if you mix up those names you are going to confuse yourself and anybody who reads your code.

Answer (score 1):

The `.layer.cornerRadius` part will be accessible only on `UIImageView` instance that is `myImage` in your case.

The `myImage.image` points to `UIImage` that won't give you access for `.layer.cornerRadius` part.

The `UIImage` is the image resource that you wish to see on screen while the `UIImageView` is the one that's presenting that resource on screen.

Here's what you can do -

```
myImage.layer.cornerRadius = myImage.frame.size.height/2
myImage.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: I see, thank you so much! I need to clarify one thing, when I am writing
myImage.image = UIImage(named: ("icon"))
why can't I write:
myImage = UIImage(named: ("icon"))?

Comment: `myImage.image = UIImage(named: "icon")` should be fine. `"icon"` is a `String` and that's what's needed there. Just get rid of the paranthesis around it.

Comment: I think Nikki's question is about the bit on the left side of the equals sign. the thing called "myImage" is not an image, it's an image **view**. As I said in my answer, you need to be careful and consistent in the way you name your variables to avoid this sort of confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You say you are trying to make a `UIImageView` into a circular shape. Then you show code `image.layer.cornerRadius = image.frame.size.height/2`. If you are working with an image **view**, name it `myImageView`, or `imageView`, not `image`. In the rest of my answer I refer to an image view named `myImageView`.

`UIView` objects have lots of different properties. Open the Xcode documentation and look up the `UIView` class reference for more information about the many properties of `UIView` objects.

UIKit is an object-oriented framework, so classes inherit from other classes. A `UIImageView` is a subclass of `UIView`. It has all the properties of it's parent class, plus properties unique to an image view.

A `UIImageView` is a view that is meant to display an image. In addition to `UIView` properties, it has a property `image` which holds the image the image view is supposed to display.

If you declare an image view:

```
@IBOutlet myImageView: UIImageView
```

Then you might install an image into that image view using code like

```
myImageView.image = UIImage(named: "icon")
```

That says "Evaluate the stuff on the right side of the equals sign. Assign the result of that to the thing on the left side of the equals sign."

`UIImage(named:)` tries to load a `UIImage` with a specific name from your app's "bundle" (The folder that contains all the stuff in your app.) If it succeeds, it returns an image. If not, it returns nil.

`myImageView.image` refers to the `image` property of the `UIImageView` `myImageView`. So, that code says "Try to load an image named 'icon' from the app's directory, and install it into the image view `myImageView`.")

---

### Layers:

All `UIView` objects have a "backing layer". Under the covers, UIKit uses the CoreAnimation framework to draw the view to the screen, and the main object in Core Animation that draws to the screen is a `CALayer`.

When you say `myImageView.layer.cornerRadius = myImageView.frame.size.height/2`, you are saying "calculate 1/2 of the height of my image view's frame (The rectangle that defines it's place on the screen) and use that to set the corner radius of the view's layer."

What that does, for square views (in combination with the next line of your code, `myImageView.clipsToBounds = true`) is to make the view's layer (The thing that's drawn to the screen) into a circle shape. The corners of the square view are clipped away, and all the user can see is the circular part in the middle.